# Updating Lucene index strategies

Tags: php, design-patterns, content-management-system, lucene

i'm integrating Lucene in a cms. I don't have a clue about how updating an index work. I know how to create and update it but i would like to know if there are smart strategies to keep the index updated. Do i need to update the index everytime a content is added to the DB? Does Lucene have good performances?

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a document in lucene, you have to delete it and re-add it. And yes, lucene is VERY fast.

Comment: `Updating index` doesn't mean updating a document.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you need the data added to DB to be searchable as soon as it it added. (more real time like)
That would not be a nice performance, if you have heavy and frequent updates in the db.

Doing incremental updates to your index would be fine (data import handler supports is out of the box), which would allow you to index only the incremental items added to db during the time frame from the last build time.

Lucene performances are too good.
You can optimize you index periodically further for better performance.

Comment: Yeah, i would like something in real time. Actually all the installations of this cms are really small.

Do you know an example of all this stuff, or maybe an open source project that implements zend lucene?